# Please let me know whether my java code is right or not?

Tags: java, junit, selenium, selenium-rc

When I run the java code I am getting the below error.. Below i have given my Java code... Please correct me if i am going wrong...

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found in pass
    at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:47)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite$1.runTest(TestSuite.java:90)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:130)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:120)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:230)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;
public class pass extends SeleneseTestCase {
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        setUp("https://secure02.monilink.co.uk/", "*chrome");
    }
    public pass() throws Exception {
/******** Below I am using my test environment URL **************/
        selenium.open("http:www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com")
        selenium.type("username", "RSRK1");
        selenium.type("password", "");
        selenium.click("_Continue1_button");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.type("username", "S10");
        selenium.type("password", "56454");
        selenium.click("_Continue1_button");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("link=Payments");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("link=Pay Credit Card");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("link=Select Card");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("link=exact:DEF Credit Card ************2016 Due Date: 19/09/10");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("link=Select Account");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("link=Current Account Created for Testing Purpose 11111111114 Balance: INR 6000.00");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.type("amount", "20.00");
        selenium.type("transferDate", "190211");
        selenium.click("_Continue1_button");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("link=Confirm");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("link=Main menu");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("link=Payments");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("link=View and Pay Bills");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("_Select+bill1_button");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("link=B.S.N.L, PUNJAB INR 135.00 due by 27/09/10");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("_Select+account+or+card2_button");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("link=Testing Account 11111111120 Balance: INR 1358.32");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.type("paymentDateString", "190211");
        selenium.click("_Continue3_button");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("link=Edit");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.type("paymentDateString", "200211");
        selenium.click("_Continue3_button");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("link=Confirm");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("link=Main menu");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("link=Logout");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("link=Yes");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change the `pass()` method into something like `testSomething()`. You need to prefix your method name with `test` if you want to run JUnit. Or you can annotate your test method with `@Test`.

e.g:

```
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;

public class pass extends SeleneseTestCase {
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        setUp("https://secure02.monilink.co.uk/", "*chrome");
    }

    public testMePlease() throws Exception {

    }
}
```

Comment: You menat to say the below i need to change... Please let me know little clear, i am new to java and selenium                     public pass() throws Exception {  selenium.open("http:www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com")

Comment: Also, traditionally Java classes are `NamedLikeThis` ("camel case" with the first letter in upper case).

Answer (score 0):

JUnit is complaining because it can't find any tests. All of your test code is inside of your constructor. Create a void method with the `@Test` attribute before it. Put your selenium steps in it. JUnit will then find it and run it as a test.

Comment: public pass() throws Exception {
/******** Below I am using my test environment URL **************/
        selenium.open("http:www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com")

Comment: You mwnat to say the above i need to change... Please let me know little clear, i am new to java and selenium..

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this:

```
    import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;
public class pass extends SeleneseTestCase {
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        setUp("https://secure02.monilink.co.uk/", "*chrome");
    }
    public testPass() throws Exception {
/******** Below I am using my test environment URL **************/
        selenium.open("http:www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com")
        selenium.type("username", "RSRK1");
        selenium.type("password", "");
        selenium.click("_Continue1_button");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.type("username", "S10");
        selenium.type("password", "56454");
        selenium.click("_Continue1_button");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("link=Payments");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("link=Pay Credit Card");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("link=Select Card");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("link=exact:DEF Credit Card ************2016 Due Date: 19/09/10");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("link=Select Account");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("link=Current Account Created for Testing Purpose 11111111114 Balance: INR 6000.00");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.type("amount", "20.00");
        selenium.type("transferDate", "190211");
        selenium.click("_Continue1_button");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("link=Confirm");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("link=Main menu");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("link=Payments");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("link=View and Pay Bills");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("_Select+bill1_button");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("link=B.S.N.L, PUNJAB INR 135.00 due by 27/09/10");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("_Select+account+or+card2_button");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("link=Testing Account 11111111120 Balance: INR 1358.32");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.type("paymentDateString", "190211");
        selenium.click("_Continue3_button");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("link=Edit");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.type("paymentDateString", "200211");
        selenium.click("_Continue3_button");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("link=Confirm");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("link=Main menu");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("link=Logout");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("link=Yes");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting the below error when i run the script java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not start Selenium session: Failed to start new browser session: Unable to delete file C:\DOCUME~1\SN2002~1.CAM\LOCALS~1\Temp\customProfileDird955037e3a5843a8a6b701c01f1ac5bb\parent.lock
 at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.start(DefaultSelenium.java:89)
 at com.example.tests.flight.setUp(flight.java:11)
 at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:132)
 at com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleneseTestCase.runBare(SeleneseTestCase.java:212)
 at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)

Comment: Can you please look the above error....why it is coming? any one please clarify me..